# Run model from python .. module object not callable

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, modelbuilder

Having issues to run a model from python, below the actual code , always return 
module object not callable.
ArcMap 10.1 using arcPy esri python 64-bit

Any ideas why?

```
    import arcpy

        try:
            arcpy.ImportToolbox("c:/test/geocode.tbx")
            arcpy.Model_41(<param>,<param>)
        except Exception as e:
            print e.message


error >> 'module' object is not callable
```

Removing try/except as suggested.

```
    import arcpy

    arcpy.ImportToolbox("c:/test/geocode.tbx")
    arcpy.Model_41("<param>,<param>")


error >>TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you need to set a temporary alias on your toolbox (or a permanent one via its Properties) as described in the [Help for ImportToolbox (arcpy)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018v0000005z000000):

> If the toolbox does not have an alias, the module_name is required.
>
> When a tool is accessed through the ArcPy site package, the toolbox
>   alias where the tool is contained is a required suffix
>   (arcpy._). Since ArcPy depends on toolbox aliases to
>   access and execute the correct tool, aliases are extremely important
>   when importing custom toolboxes. A good practice is to always define a
>   custom toolbox's alias. However, if the toolbox alias is not defined,
>   a temporary alias can be set as the second parameter.

Try this:

```
import arcpy
arcpy.ImportToolbox("c:/test/geocode.tbx","test")
arcpy.Model_41_test("<param>,<param>")
```

Comment: Thanks that was it , the toolbox alias name in the ImportToolbox method and then calling it by the Model name (Model_41) followed by _<toolbox alias name> (test).